# What are the drawbacks of using Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Why are many organisations not using Storyboard for developing iPhone apps?
What are drawbacks of using Storyboard?

Comment: Question not suitable for this site. There is no "correct" answer.

Comment: you can refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360826/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-storyboarding . I have found it in a minute.

Comment: sir actually i have read about storyboard and also implemented . but i want to know the drawbacks of storyboard. Bacause it is not using in my company

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky one to answer, but there's a couple of reasons it's not taken off massively that I'm aware of.

- Code versioning tools: Using xibs and Storyboard files with `git/SVN/hg` is at times a painful experience. They're essentially XML files so they can be versioned and controlled but there's usually a lot of headaches in terms of merging. Once you've done a dozen so merges you start getting sick of it. Storyboard has even more going on for merge processes to deal with than just standard xibs.
- Complex interfaces: I'm using Storyboard for a semi-complex app, and I can't say it was a brilliant decision. Once you've pushed past about 8-10 screens navigating Storyboard is a complete pain, if you zoom out you can place elements, if you click on a Storyboard screen it doesn't automatically jump to it in the side bar. It also sucks down performance after a certain point, and it's horrible to use on a screen smaller than 17".
- Experience: A lot of iOS/OS X developers are more familiar with traditional xib/programatic interface development, whilst Storyboard is there they'd need to learn a new tool to do the same job. It's an investment most people don't want, or need to make.

There's a lot to like, it's good for rapid prototyping, but there's some serious things to consider for people using it at scale.

Answer (score -2):

For me its the need of a real big screen(may be projector ) if you wana make iPad apps is one of the drawbacks.

Many organizations do not use because of inertia in favor of previous tech.

Comment: listed a draw back when asked for read the question